# Why am I creating two pages in the title when I dont want an initial blank page?

Tags: code

[image: blank page occurs]

The $1$ at the bottom of the top bage is just there- the rest of it is blank. Also I am trying to make my title go to the left and it's not working. Any help? This is my first time using LaTeX by the way. Does left flush command work for this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\title{English}
\author{Henry Lyuieuasjhf}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{flushleft}
\section{Introduction}
Hello this is a practice!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to align the title to the left, you would need to redefine the `\maketitle` command. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter % To allow the use of @
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \begin{flushleft}%
        {\Large\bfseries\@title}\\\medskip%
        {\scshape\@author}\\%
        {\small\@date}%
    \end{flushleft}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{English}
\author{Henry Lyuieuasjhf}
\date{}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
    Hello this is a practice!

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Alright, thank you! What bout the problem of the initial blank page? Actually, the blank page doesn't happen when I put the code into overleaf the online latex editor

Comment: @user71207 The blank page is probably because `\maketitle` internally has a `\clearpage`, and somehow `\begin{flushleft}` gets in before it, acting like `\null`. As for Overleaf, I think it might have used some way to detect and remove empty pages in the pdf file.

Comment: If you have time, can you tell me what you did that's different? What is \renewcommand and what do you mean by allow use of @?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\oldcommand}{new definition}` is a way to redefine a command. `\@title` is used internally in `\title` to store the title string, similar with `\@author` and `\@date`. But `@` is a little special in LaTeX, so we need to change its cat-code before use it in the macro name, thus `\makeatletter` should be used (and after all these `\makeatother` is to restore the normal cat-code value, as far as I understood).